# Data frame rows and columns replication from 1 frame to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to group a specific column value x of column A of DF1 as a group name and aggregate the same row values present in column B as a series or a list

Then these series/list of values of column B  replace DF2 Column A value x at first occurrence and duplicate the rows for the length of the values in series/list and add the values in the DF2 column A.

```
DF1:

A   B     
x   1  
x   2  
x   3       


DF2:
***
Red    Blue  Green  Yellow
x      10     car    four
x      11     Bus    six
y      12     bike   two
z      13     cycle  two
```

I want the DF2 or a new DF to be formed as

```
DF3:

Red    Blue  Green  Yellow  
1      10     car    four
2      10     car    four
3      10     car    four
1      11     Bus    six
2      11     Bus    six
3      11     Bus    six
y      12     bike   two
z      13     cycle  two
```

Can someone help on the logic? preferably using pandas with less iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You could do an `outer` [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and use [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) to combine the values in column `A` of `df1` with column `B`:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on ='A', right_on='Red', how='outer').bfill(axis=1)\
   .drop(['A','Red'], axis=1).rename(columns={'B':'Red'})

   Red Blue  Green Yellow
0   1   10    car   four
1   1   11    Bus    six
2   2   10    car   four
3   2   11    Bus    six
4   3   10    car   four
5   3   11    Bus    six
6   y   12   bike    two
7   z   13  cycle    two
```

Comment: nice one. :) +1 from me. (you could also tweak this a little to get the exact output which the OP has posted. :))

Comment: Thanks @anky_91! This was the answer to the original question, which had a different `df2`, I only realised of the change from your comment

Comment: Does it suit your problem @D83? Please let me know otherwise instead of changing the question :-)

Comment: Apologies for the edit. I did not clearly express the complexity of the requirement. That's the reason for the change in the DF2. Kindly check this scenario as the final requirement. The merge function will not provide the required output as the column values and the dataframe structure are different from DF1

Comment: Unfortunately the output donot match my requirement.  The DF1 column A value "x" is a group name that is repeated with a series of values represented in column B "1,2,3". I need to take these "1,2,3" and insert them in DF2 column Red for every occurrence of "x". That means i need to replicate the whole row for every insert of 1 , 2, 3,... . So Column RED in the example has two "x" occurrences.  thats why the values are like 1,2,3,1,2,3. Rest of the columns and rows should not be sorted or changed.